# Co dependent fields in Odoo 9.0 view

Tags: odoo, view

Hello everybody and thanks for taking the time to read my question:

I need to make two fields update on each other changes in my view, let's say one of them list's ingredients and the other lists food requirements

```
requirements = fields.Selection([(0,"Vegan"),(1,"Lactose intolerant")])
ingredients_id = fields.Many2Many(comodel_name="sample.ingredients")
```

What i need is to update `ingredients_id`'s domain to show only those who match a `requirement` and vice versa, if you happend to select and ingredient the other field selecting the proper `requirement`. I'm thinking about making field `A` a computed field depending on field`B` and then add an `on_change` to field `B` that updates field `A`. But I'm pretty certain that will turn into some kind of infinite loop situation. Is that my only option or am I missing something obviuos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @api.depends decorator and pass both fields as parameters in the decorator. This will trigger function every time on change on both values and will be dependent on each other.

```
@api.depends('requirements','ingredients_id')
def function (self): ....
    do something....
    return
```

Comment: Wouldn't that take me back to the "possible infinite loop situation"? If I change field `A` and  field `B` computes a new value that would trigger the computation of a new field `A` and so on

Comment: No using separate functions won't do that.

Comment: I've found a workaround in my solution that doesn't need for those fields to be co dependent anymore, thanks for your answers anyway